# Driver Manager through Proxy

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, proxy

I'm having some issues getting drivers through the Driver Manager on Linux Mint 17.3. I am currently behind a corporate proxy and do have my system variables setup appropriately e.g. `http_proxy` & `https_proxy`. I have no other proxy related issues except for use with Driver Manager which gives the following error upon opening.

> Drivers cannot be installed.
>   Please connect to the Internet or insert the Linux Mint installation DVD (or USB stick).

Does anyone have an approach to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Driver Manager from the terminal using command:

```
sudo -E mintdrivers
```

Now, it will preserve the proxy for Driver Manager

Answer (score 0):

By modifying '*check_connectivity*' function from following py script it resolved by issue.

Script location:
/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintdrivers/mintdrivers.py

Code:

```
def check_connectivity(self, reference):
    try:
        #Proxy
        *proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy.example.com:3128'}*
        urllib.request.urlopen(reference, timeout=10, proxies=proxies)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

same issue encountered with mint 19.2. it worked after a deeper modification of /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintdrivers/mintdrivers.py:

```
def check_connectivity(self, reference):
    try:
        proxies = {'http': 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000', 'https': 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000/', 'ftp': 'ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000/'}
        proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        urllib.request.urlopen(reference, timeout=10)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

then run the driver manager with command-line "sudo -E mintdrivers" helps to catch any error printout.